# Как с помощью checkbox отключить thead в таблице?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня есть таблица вот такого вида:

```
<table id="contact" class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Сортировать А-Я</th>
            <th>Телефон</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src='Img/persons/<%# Eval("img2")%>.jpg' width="100" height="100" class="img-circle" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <b class="lead text-success text-center"><%# Eval("lastname")%>  <%# Eval("firstname")%>  <%# Eval("middlename")%></b>
            <br />
            <%# Eval("company")%>
            <p><small><%# Eval("position")%></small> </p>
            <asp:Button ID="ShowContact" runat="server" Text="Узнать Всё" OnCommand="ShowContact_Command" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-xs" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <%# Eval("work_phone1")%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%# Eval("email1")%>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Как мне с помощью Jquery при нажатии в чекбокс скрыть вот это:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Сортировать А-Я</th>
        <th>Телефон</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Попробовал несколько способов не помогло.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.checkbox').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('table#contact thead').hide();
    } else {
      $('table#contact thead').show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="contact" class="table table-striped table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Сортировать А-Я</th>
      <th>Телефон</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
</div>
```